# dynamically radiobuttonlist selectedindex doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I got 5 radiobuttonlists in my site,

```
<div class="col-md-6">

 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="CR1" CssClass="radioButtonList" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
 <asp:ListItem Text='1' Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text='2' Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text='3' Value="3"></asp:ListItem>                           
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

from a button I want to clear all option selections so I use the code below

```
 For i = 1 To 5

        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = Me.Page.FindControl("CR" & i )
        rbl.SelectedIndex = -1

    Next
```

but this doesn't work, when I use the CR1.SelectedIndex = -1 works fine!!

Any suggestions why I can't work this witin a loop?

Comment: Did you debug to see if you get the radiobuttonlist by FindControl?

Comment: i got a 'System.NullReferenceException' on  rbl.SelectedIndex = -1

Comment: on debug I also see that findcontrol value is Nothing, I can't understand why..???

Answer (score 0):

You could not find the `RadioButtonList` by [Page.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) as it is probably not top level container control immediate child. Me.Page.FindControl does not search down the hierarchy recursively the top level container. You need immediate parent of radiobuttonlist.

[Page.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The method searches only the page's immediate, or top-level,
>   container; it does not recursively search for controls in naming
>   containers contained on the page. To access controls in a subordinate naming 
>   container, call the FindControl method of that container.

You can make the parent div server accessible and find through it.

```
<div id="divRBL" runat="server" class="col-md-6">
```

In Code behind

```
Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = divRBL.FindControl("CR" & i )
```

If you have multiple divs containg RadioButtonList then you can assign ids in sequence to make their ids at runtime as you are doing for `RadioButtonLists` in `FindControl`.

Comment: Is the RadioButtonList in GridView or Repeater etc? Please related HTML showing the hierarchy of its all parents.

Comment: i tried all parents ...the radiobuttonlist is in a container - form - Panel - panel body - div the error for each parent is : {InnerText = {System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot get inner content of bdPanel because the contents are not literal.
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.get_InnerHtml()
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.get_InnerText()}}

Comment: Please add related HTML